Code splitting by route does not pull in child components only used on that route
I have many Vue components like the following:
<template>
  <CommonChild :content="content" />
</template>

<script>
import CommonChild from '@/views/CommonChild.vue';
import { UniqueChild1 } from '@/library.js';

export default {
  name: 'Example1',
  components: {
    CommonChild
  },
  computed: {
    content: function () {
      return {
        component: UniqueChild1
      };
    }
  }
};
</script>

Each has their own lazy-loaded route. The CommonChild is used in all of them, so it is code split out appropriately. But the UniqueChild1 is a different import in each Vue file. The component's imported from the library.js file are only ever used by one component each. But the build always produces a large library.js bundle. So no matter which route I go to, it has to load the entire library (2MB) before the page can load and only use a small part of the library on the specific page.
The outcome is essentially:
site/assets/Example1.js         0.6 kB
site/assets/Example2.js         0.7 kB
site/assets/Example3.js         0.9 kB
site/assets/Example4.js         0.8 kB
...
site/assets/CommonChild.js      1.0 kB
site/assets/index.js          500.0 kB
site/assets/library.js      2,000.0 kB

Where what I want is this:
site/assets/Example1.js        40.0 kB
site/assets/Example2.js        80.0 kB
site/assets/Example3.js        90.0 kB
site/assets/Example4.js        25.0 kB
...
site/assets/CommonChild.js      1.0 kB
site/assets/index.js          500.0 kB

How do I force Vite to break up the library, so that the parts being imported by the routes live in that route's chunk?

Vue 3.5
Vite 5.4


Please, provide your current vite config for completeness. Did you try to use dynamic imports and async components? That's a way to force splitting. Also it's unclear what's with "library.js      2,000.0 kB" vs "index.js          500.0 kB". If you don't want UniqueChild1 to be included into library.js/index.js it is then don't make it a part of it, i.e import it from UniqueChild1.vue instead of library.js. Even if it's supposed to became importable from library.js, it could be split into UniqueChild1.js to be reused between Example1.js and library.js/index.js. But not the way you listed

I assumed that if library.js imported and then exported a file, and I then imported that file from library.js in another place and never used it anywhere else that Vite/ESBuild would be clever enough to just sort all that out. But alas, you are correct. I stopped importing from library.js anywhere in my code and instead grabbed the source files directly and everything code splits as I originally anticipated.
